# How to update an existing spacy model?

Tags: python, spacy

I'm developing a named entity recognition function for my master thesis.
I want to utilize the "en_core_web_sm" language package and train the ability to identify products.

before training the model the untrained model ("en_core_web_sm") is able to identify different entities like 'PERSON', 'ORG', 'GPE', 'DATE',...
in a "validation sentence. Products are sporadically identified but usually the label is incorrect.
After training the model ONLY entities of type 'PRODUCT' are identified but no other entities eventough there should be persons, Orgs,... identified.

I have the feeling that my model is forgetting other entities and after the training "knows" only the product entity.

This is my training code:

```
#nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")

optimizer = nlp.create_optimizer()
#other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != "ner"]

pipe_exceptions = ["ner", "trf_wordpiecer", "trf_tok2vec"]
other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe not in pipe_exceptions]
losses = {}
with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes): # only train NER
    for itn in range(100):
        print(itn)
        random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
        losses = {}
        for text, annotations in TRAIN_DATA:
            doc = nlp.make_doc(text)
            example = Example.from_dict(doc, annotations)
            nlp.update([example], drop=0.35, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
            print(losses)
```

How can update the default "en_core_web_sm" model to keep the ability to identify PERSON, DATE, ORG,... but to adapt the trained PRODUCT part?

Comment: You are experiencing "catastrophic forgetting", please see the FAQ on this. Also we strongly recommend you don't write your own training loop, try using the config-based training instead. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8226#:~:text=my%20retrained%20model%20forgot%20pretrained%20entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran indeed into a catastrophic forgetting issue. I solved it by providing other entity labeled training data too.

Comment: please, share how you solve it